# How to have unique elements in integer array within a map?

Tags: dictionary, go

I have a map of string and int array as shown below which is being populated -

```
  var customerCatalog = make(map[string][]int64)
  for ... {
        var data = "....."
        for _, catalogId := range data.Catalogs {
            var ok bool
            var keys []int64
            var tmp interface{}
            cusId := strconv.FormatInt(int64(catalogId), 10)
            if tmp, ok = customerCatalog[cusId]; !ok {
                keys = []int64{}
            } else {
                keys = tmp.([]int64)
            }
            keys = append(keys, data.ProductId)
            customerCatalog[cusId] = keys
        }
    }
```

Here `data.Catalogs` is int32 array. And `data.ProductId` is int64. So I need to loop over `data.Catalogs` array and populate my `customerCatalog` map with unique array values for each `data.ProductId` key.

As you can see I have value of map as integer array which can have duplicate values in it. I want to make sure integer array for particular key in the map should have unique values in them. Since go doesn't support generics so that is why we don't have set so how should we handle this case here?

Comment: Go does support generics in 1.18 but I don't know why that would be a problem. Without generics: https://github.com/emirpasic/gods#sets, with generics: https://github.com/bradenaw/juniper/tree/main/sets

Comment: I am still on 1.17 as of now. I don't want to bring 3rd party library here if there is a way to do directly without using it?

Comment: Go doesn't have a set in the std lib and I would say it's an ideal use case. I don't see the point of implementing it yourself when there is a very well tested and used library (gods) with over 11k stars tbh! Whether it's in the std library or not doesn't affect your app negatively in terms of performance or size (swapping one for the other). It's a simple and small data structure: https://github.com/emirpasic/gods/blob/master/sets/hashset/hashset.go

Comment: Let me look into it @Dominic. If you can provide an example for my current usecase on how can I use it then it will be of great help. Does that mean I also need to change from standard map to hashmap and then only I can use value of map as hashset? If you can provide an example for my usecase then it will be of great help.

Comment: can you share an example of the data in and what you expect to get out plz?

Comment: It will be tough for me to provide `data` as it is coming from reading parquet file but any example which demonstrates on how to use set as the value of my map then I will be able to understand that. `map[string]hashset` maybe this is the way I need to declare?

Comment: No need at all for generics to get sets in Go. Relevant reading at https://yourbasic.org/golang/implement-set/

Comment: @Dominic I updated my question to add more details about code and what is `data.Catalogs` data type and all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Since go doesn't support generics so that is why we don't have set

Sets are often implemented using the keys of a hash table; ignore the values.

In Go, use a `map[int64]bool`.

```
// Check if an array contains only unique values.
func is_unique(array []int64) bool {
  var unique = map[int64]bool{}

  for _,v := range(array) {
    if unique[v] {
      return false
    }
    unique[v] = true
  }

  return true
}

// Return a deduplicated array
func uniq(array []int64) []int64 {
  var unique = map[int64]bool{}
  keys := make([]int64, 1)

  for _,v := range(array) {
    if _, ok := unique[v]; !ok {
      keys = append(keys, v)
      unique[v] = true
    }
  }

  return keys
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you also help me on how can I use this with my current code in the question? I am just confuse on how will this work with my current code.

Comment: @AndyP It's unclear to me what your code is supposed to do. You can use the keys of a `map` as an array which can only hold unique values; a set. If you're adding just a single value it would probably be faster to simply scan the array to ensure the value is not already in the array.

Comment: I updated my question to add more details. Basically `data.Catalogs` is just `int32` array which I am iterating over and then for each `data.ProductId` I need to have unique array of int32 as a value in the map. Sorry I tried following your suggestion but I couldn't understand on how to make it work for my use case. Let me know if my updated code in the question help you in providing an example for me.

Comment: @AndyP If you want to ensure an array does not contain duplicates, run it through `uniq`. For example: `customerCatalog[cusId] = uniq(keys)`.

Comment: yeah that makes sense but it means for every append I am making to keys array, it will keep deduping every time. It is expensive for me as my outer and inner for loops run on large data sets. Is there any other better way?

Comment: @AndyP Deduplicate after you're done appending. Or do something else, you have the basic technique of using `map` as a set.

Comment: @AndyP Or skip the array and store them as a set: `var customerCatalog = make(map[string]map[int64]bool)`.  Then to add a value `if v, ok = customerCatalog[cusId]; ok { v[data.ProductId] = true } else { customerCatalog[cusId] = map[int64]bool{ data.ProductId: true }`